# Multiple Select statements in one query - PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tables:
Players:
ID(PK), Name, Team, Pos

Matchups:
matchupID(PK), player1ID, player2ID
player1ID and 2 are FKs to Players.ID

I'd like to select the name of both players when pulling but can't get the query correct. I do NOT want a union here.

Something along the lines of this, I'm also open to a better suggestion for formatting the two tables I have.

```
$queryString = "SELECT Players.name FROM Players
                    INNER JOIN Matchup WHERE Players.ID = player1ID,
                    SELECT Players.name FROM Players
                    INNER JOIN Matchup WHERE Players.ID = player2ID";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoudl join two time Player and not matchup

```
  $queryString = "select a.name, b.name from Matchup as c
            Inner Join Players as a on c.player1ID = a.ID
            Inner Join Players as b on c.player2ID  = b.ID";
```